# How to load UIWebView in infinite UIScrollView without reload twice?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview, infinite

Using 3 UIWebView pages(0,1,2) to simulate infinite pages in a UISccrollView, it works OK on scrolling and changing content.

The problem is that the currWebView reloads the new content once more from the old content when stop scrolling. How can I move the pages smoothly and shows the currWebView withou a flash?

```
func loadPage(theVolume:Int, theChapter:Int, chapterArr:NSArray, onPage page: Int) {

    switch(page) {
    case 0:
        prevWebView.loadRequest(webViewRequest);
        break
    case 1:            
        // I try to replace the following line with: currWebView = prevWebView, it shows blank
        currWebView.loadRequest(webViewRequest);
        break
    case 2:
        nextWebView.loadRequest(webViewRequest);
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}


func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // moving forward
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x > mainScrollView!.frame.size.width) {

        prevChapterArr = currChapterArr
        loadPage(volumeNum, theChapter: chapterNum, chapterArr: prevChapterArr, onPage: 0)

        var theNext = getNext(volumeNum, theChapter: chapterNum)
        volumeNum = theNext["volume"]!
        chapterNum = theNext["chapter"]!
        currChapterArr = nextChapterArr
        loadPage(volumeNum, theChapter: chapterNum, chapterArr: currChapterArr, onPage: 1)

        theNext = getNext(volumeNum, theChapter: chapterNum)
        nextVolume = theNext["volume"]!
        nextChapter = theNext["chapter"]!
        nextChapterArr = getLection(nextVolume, theChapter: nextChapter)
        loadPage(nextVolume, theChapter: nextChapter, chapterArr: nextChapterArr, onPage: 2)

    }

    // moving backward
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x < mainScrollView!.frame.size.width) {
        // similar codes as above
    }

    // reset offset to the middle page
    self.mainScrollView!.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(mainScrollView!.frame.size.width, 0, mainScrollView!.frame.size.width, mainScrollView!.frame.size.height), animated: false)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following codes to get it works and need no request all the webviews again.

```
let tmp = prevWebView
prevWebView = currWebView
currWebView = nextWebView
nextWebView = tmp
nextWebview.loadRequest(webViewRequest)
```